# Run a polynomial regression without combinations of the features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, polynomials, non-linear-regression

I am running a polynomial regression for order p. To make it simple, we use order `p = 2` in this question.

Suppose we have `X` with two feature `x1, x2` and `y`. And I am trying to run a polynomial regression of

`y = ε + α + β1•x1 + β2•x2 + β3•x1^2 + β4•x2^2`

I find that the sklearn have a `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures`. However, if I use order p = 2 and it automatically gives the combination of features. It will result in a regression of:

`y = ε + α + β1•x1 + β2•x2 + β3•x1^2 + β4•x2^2 + β5•x1x2`

However, I do not want the combination of the features, i.e. things like `x1x2`. Is there any package that can do the polynomial regress as I wished?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html) seems to serve your needs.

For even more specific needs use this [statistics tool](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Tbh, this seems like very weird idea to me. A lot of strength of poly features come out of interaction features.

I'm pretty sure there's nothing built-in, but

- you can take a look at `PolynomialFeatures` pre-processor, and make your own with modification. You'll need to "revert" logic of `interaction_only` parameter
- just build your pre-processor, your case is quite simple, `.fit` will do smth like `concat(a, a**2)`